# Google Places Api: Not able to display all search results

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am unable to display all the results requested from the Google Places Api..

```
var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitute, Longitute);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: Latlng,
                    zoom: 10});
        var request = {location: Latlng,types: [type]};
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results,status,pagination) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
        }
        if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
         pagination.nextPage(); }}}

   function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,zIndex: 100,position: place.geometry.location});
            var request = {reference : place.reference,};
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.getDetails(request, function detailsDisplay(details, status){
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(status);
                    $('#placesdata').append('<tr><td><a href='+details.url+'>' + details.name+ '</a></td></tr>');
                } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    createMarker(place);
                    }, 200);}});} };
```

i used pagination and getting 60 results but only can display 20..and 40 using settimeout() function...getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are getting `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` on line:

```
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
```

because you are already creating Markers, which eats up your quota.

Try queuing the details requests for after you have all the list completed, and adding the same timeout logic to check for `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`  on this line.

For example you could say:

```
if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
  //add all places to the list
  setTimeout('pagination.nextPage()',2000);
}  else {
  createMarkers(placesList);
}
```

btw. the Places equivalent of  `google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` is  `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` and you should use this when  using Places.

HTH

Comment: still unable to display 60 results...any other way

Comment: what erros are you getting now ? You will need to add a sleep function before you request the next batch, I missed that last time. Just like the docs say: "nextPage() a function that will return the next set of results. After executing a search, you must wait two seconds before the next page of results will be available.". Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665684/more-than-20-results-by-pagination-with-google-places-api for an answer to the same question.

Comment: sure. here is a full sample without geting the details, but with 6o results returned: http://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~kaskader/places_60.html

Answer (score 1):

I have done all those effort. Thanks for you guys for posting but i got solution. really a good solution. See working example below.

When you call this method to check if it has pages or not

```
if(pagination.hasNextPage){
    pagination.nextPage(); // let this do recursive loop against request.
}
```

// when nextPage() request finishes

```
if(pagination.b == null){
```

// here pagination.b has next page token. so it return null when last request sent.

```
createMarkers(placesList);

}
```