# how to create a map with list of food and liquor stores

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to create a google map comparing the amount of food and liquor stores in NYC. I don't have much experience with the google maps api or places api so I'm really confused. Is there a way I can place hundreds of marks around NYC that are a certain color so you know it is a food store (say red) and then corresponding liquor stores would have a different color (blue). I don't know the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can also use pagination to retrieve more places...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665684/more-than-20-results-by-pagination-with-google-places-api

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the Places API to place hundreds of locations, it is limited (20 results per call).  The Places API is intended to give you the 20 closest results to your location, or the 20 closest matches to your query.

If you have the locations or the addresses, you can display them on a map, and categorize them with different colored markers, but you will need to get the data from somewhere other than Google for what you want to do.

[Example categories map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) ported from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial.